# ajax cross domain failed to get response

Tags: ajax, https, http-post, web.xml

I have two servers:
Server 1 (URL: https://server1.AAA.com) and 
Server 2 (URL: https://server2.AAA.com)

In Server 1 JSP page, I try to use ajax to send a POST request to Server 2.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "https://server2.AAA.com/servlet",
data: 'test',
success: function(data, textSuccess) {
       alert(data);
 }
 error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert('error');
 },
});
```

In Server 2, I checked that it has received the request from Server 1, and I tried to response the following message:

```
doPost(...) {
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.getwriter().write("success");
}
```

However, I found that Server 1 cannot receive the response data from Server 2, it went to the error alert. I have totally no idea why such a situation happened. I have already set response header for all origins, and did set the security constraint in my application's web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>      
<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>test</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <http-method>POST</http-method>
 </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

Please tell me what I am still missing / what should I check.

Comment: data got to be a key value pair

Comment: check data-type and content-type parameters for the ajax requests? they should match with server..

Comment: sorry, the data 'test' is just an example, I have passed data: 'key1:value1' in the request, and I can see Server 2 can retrieve the value1. It is fine. The question is I cannot get the response from Server 2. 
I have set 
datatype : "html",
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
but still can't.